# calculating catalan numbers using memoization

Tags: python, memoization, catalan

I am tring to use memoization in order to calculate catalan numbers, but it just does not seem to work, what do I need to change?

```
def catalan_mem(n, memo = None):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    if memo == None:
        memo = {}
    b=0
    if n not in memo:
       for i in range (n):
           b+=((catalan_mem(i),memo)[0])*((catalan_mem(n-1-i),memo)[0])
    memo[n]=b
    return memo[n]
```

thank you!

Comment: "Does not seem to work" isn't a good problem description.  Does it give an exception?  Does it give the right answer the first time and the wrong answer after that?  Does it compute the wrong values?  Et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `catalan_mem` on an `n` in `memo` then you replace `memo[n]` with 0. This is probably not what you intend.

Without parsing the logic further, this suggests `memo[n]=b` should be inside of the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the lru decorator:

```
from functools import lru_cache
import time
start_time = time.time()
@lru_cache(maxsize=500)
def catalan_memo(n: int) -> int: # Do not add more arguments.
    """
    Return the nth catalan number using memoization.
    """
  
        # Base Case
    if n <= 1 :
        return 1 
    # Recursive Case
    res = 0 
    for i in range(n):
        res += catalan_recur(i) * catalan_recur(n-i-1)
  
    return res
print(catalan_memo(7))
print(time.time() - start_time)
```